# PHP login / logout system does not work correctly

Tags: php, authentication, error-handling, system, logout

I've got a problem with my login system/logout system.

So the problem is that I can not login. When I enter the correct username and password I get redirected to index.php when that is actually only going to happend after I have logged out. I think the error is in login_success.php with the `if (!isset($_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']))` line, (mittbrukarnamn = myusername), that will make the problem above, but when I remove the `!` so the `isset` is not false anymore, I can login but then the logout.php does not "work".

And I also get an error in line 19 that starts with `if ($_POST['mittbrukarnamn'] && $_POST['mittpassord'])` when I enter the wrong username or password in IE 9, or does not enter any username or password. But in Google Chrome I do not get that error. Can someone tell me if this is a safe system? I am going to add a code line later that makes the password convert to MD5 and an Admin user page.

Here is the check.php

```
    <title>Login side</title>

<?php
session_start();

// 'vert' er det same som 'host' på engelsk (ikkje så viktig).
    $vert = "localhost";
    $brukarnamn = "root";
    $passord = "";
    $db_namn = "login";
    $tbl_namn = "members";

// Tilkobling til MySQL databasen.
    mysql_connect("$vert", "$brukarnamn", "$passord") or die ("Kan dessverre ikkje koble til databasen.");
    mysql_select_db("$db_namn") or die ("Kan ikkje finna den ynkjande tabellen 'namn'.");
?>

<?php
    if ($_POST['mittbrukarnamn'] && $_POST['mittpassord']) {

      $mittbrukarnamn = $_POST['mittbrukarnamn'];
      $mittpassord = $_POST['mittpassord'];

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_namn WHERE `brukarnamn` = '$mittbrukarnamn' AND `passord` = '$mittpassord'";
// '$res' forkorting for 'resultat'.
      $res = mysql_query($sql);

// '$tell' er skreve på norsk, og er det same som 'count' på engelsk (f.eks. og telja til 10). Slek ein ikkje     trur da er 'tell' på engelsk; (ikkje så viktig).
      $tell = mysql_num_rows($res);

      if ($tell == 1) {
        $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn'];
        $_SESSION['mittpassord'];
        header ("location: login_success.php");
  } else {
        echo "Brukarnamnet eller passordet er feil.";
        header ("refresh: 2; index.php");
  }

  } else {
        echo "Vennligst tast inn eit brukarnamn og eit passord.";
        header ("refresh: 2; index.php");
  }
?>
```

And login_success.php

```
<title>Medlem side</title>

<?php
  session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn'])) {
        header("location: index.php");
}
?>

<html>
<body>
Du er innlogga.<br />
<a href="logout.php"> Logg ut</a>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope I have made clear what the problem is. Thank you for any answers :)

Some of this text is on norwegian.
(mittbrukarnamn = myusername)
(mittpassord = mypassword)

Comment: You should write comments in english )o:

Comment: Hehe, yeah I can do that next time. It just says what some of the commands means in english and etc. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its addition to Norton's answer: 
after placing the session_start() at the very beginning of the file,

replace `$_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn'];` with `$_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']='';` to set the session variable.
What you are doing now does not set the session variable , its only getting the `$_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']`

Comment: Hmm... When I replaced $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']; with $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']=''; in check.php

I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\wamp\www\TestLoggin\check.php on line 36

Comment: Aha ! After "Musa" edited it to $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']=' '; (with space between the '') insted of $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']=''; I saw what user2008945 ment! :D Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

<title>Medlem side</title>
```

not

```
<title>Medlem side</title>

<?php
  session_start();
```

You have to start session before any output.

Same in login site.

You did not get any errors?

Second. Your script is not resistant for Mysql injection attacks. Use google with PHP Mysql Injection phrase.

Comment: Hmm... I removed the <?php session_start(); ?> from all the three .php files that I use with that server from the example at the bottom, and put them like you said in the top example; but it still does not work :S

Comment: Why You don't store values in $_SESSION['key']? Try         $_SESSION['user']['name']='mittbrukarnamn'; etc. instead of $_SESSION['mittbrukarnamn']; etc. And read user2008945 answer. He have right.

Answer (score 0):

Include the `php` code at the start of your `login_success.php` file. `session` variables should be the first thing in that file.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed one problem I had :)

Answer (score 0):

Considering you are new to Register & Login and PHP, I recommend you watch this. It must clear all your doubts!

http://www.youtube.com/course?list=ECE134D877783367C7

Answer (score 0):

> // Check database to see if username and the password exist there.

```
        $query = "SELECT id, username ";
        $query .= "FROM users ";
        $query .= "WHERE username = '{$username}' ";
        $query .= "AND password= '{$password}' ";
        $query .= "LIMIT 1";
        $result_set = mysql_query($query);
        confirm_query($result_set);
        if (mysql_num_rows($result_set) == 1) {
            // username/password authenticated
            // and only 1 match
            $found_user = mysql_fetch_array($result_set);
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $found_user['id'];
            $_SESSION['username'] = $found_user['username'];

            redirect_to("whereever.php");
        } else {
            // username/password combo was not found in the database
            $message = "Username/password combination incorrect.<br />
                Please make sure your caps lock key is off and try again.";
        }
    } else {
        if (count($errors) == 1) {
            $message = "There was 1 error in the form.";
        } else {
            $message = "There were " . count($errors) . " errors in the form.";
        }
```